# SharePoint 2013 Discussion Board

Tags: discussion

How to customize the sharepoint discussion board?

Regards,
Mohamed

Answer (score 1):

1. Use SharePoint designer to modify the view. This will make the changes for the specific instance of that discussion board.
2. If you need to make the changes to the view for all discussion boards, you can either

   a) edit the `schema.xml`'s CAML for the discussion board list that is located at

   `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\DiscussionsList\Discuss\schema.xml`

   b) create your own custom discussion board list by copying the exisiting feature and modifying it to your own needs.

[AN UPDATE – HOW TO CONFIGURE A CUSTOM ITEM STYLE FOR A DISCUSSION BOARD USING THE CONTENT QUERY WEB PART](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/05/02/an-update-how-to-configure-a-custom-item-style-for-a-discussion-board-using-the-content-query-web-part-aspx/)

Comment: hi i am not able to see the discussion in the above path in server.C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\   upto features ok but not able to see discussion board.

Comment: Your version SharePoint server?

Comment: Sharepoint 2016

Comment: Oh ok got it . Now i can able to get the answer. Can we change directly schema?